# How to split each line of a text file into three parts with python

Tags: python, split, division

I have a text file that contains a string for each line

ABDASLDJIJD

HSKNKSLUDHNJJNŞKSJ

SNKJBAKHSLIJSKM

...

I just want to split each line into three parts and store each part in a different text file (first parts go first file, second parts go second file etc.)

If string can be dividible with 3 it is ok but if it cannot dividible with three I should take the most nearly value for the parts. For example if string has 14 letter, parts can be 5,5,4 or if string contains 26 letter then the parts can be 9,8,8 or 8,8,9.

Could you please help for this issue?

Answer (score 0):

You could use floor division `//` and add one if the number of the current sublist is smaller than the modulo `%`.

```
>>> n, k = 27, 3
>>> [n // k + (i < n % k) for i in range(k)]
[9, 9, 9]
>>> n, k = 25, 3
>>> [n // k + (i < n % k) for i in range(k)]
[9, 8, 8]
```

For finding the actual start- and end-indices of the substrings, you could e.g. combine this with `itertools.accumulate`:

```
>>> from itertools import accumulate
>>> string = "0123456789"
>>> n, k = len(string), 3
>>> lengths = [n // k + (i < n % k) for i in range(k)]
>>> idxs = list(accumulate([0, *lengths]))
>>> [string[a:b] for a, b in zip(idxs, idxs[1:])]
['0123', '456', '789']
```

Or make an `iter` from the string and `join` the `islices` or respective lengths:

```
>>> from itertools import islice
>>> it = iter(string)
>>> [''.join(islice(it, x)) for x in lengths]
['0123', '456', '789']
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def split_items(seq, num):
    avg = len(seq) / float(num)
    out = []
    last = 0.0

    while last < len(seq):
        out.append(seq[int(last):int(last + avg)])
        last += avg

    return out


a = "HSKNKSLUDHNJJNŞKSJ"
for item in [
    "ABDASLDJIJD",
    "HSKNKSLUDHNJJNŞKSJ",
    "SNKJBAKHSLIJSKM"
]:
    print(split_items(item, 3))

# ['ABD', 'ASLD', 'JIJD']
# ['HSKNKS', 'LUDHNJ', 'JNŞKSJ']
# ['SNKJB', 'AKHSL', 'IJSKM']
```

Answer (score 0):

Here a possibility. Before testing it, be sure to add the target paths/filenames to `string_per_files`.

```
text = """ABDASLDJIJD

HSKNKSLUDHNJJNŞKSJ

SNKJBAKHSLIJSKM"""


def new_line_sizes(n): # split line logic
    if n < 3:
        raise Exception('Error, at least 3 character per line')

    q, r = divmod(n, 3)
    v = q+1
    if r == 0:
        return n//3, n//3, n//3
    elif r == 1:
        return n//3+1, n//3, n//3
    elif r == 2:
        return n//3+1, n//3+1, n//3


# add the right target paths/filenames!
string_per_files = {'file1': {'path': 'my/path1', 'lines': []},
                    'file2': {'path': 'my/path2', 'lines': []},
                    'file3': {'path': 'my/path3', 'lines': []},}

# read from file (in this case the given string), split & classification of lines
for line in text.split():
    n1, n2, _ = new_line_sizes(len(line))
    string_per_files['file1']['lines'].append(line[:n1])
    string_per_files['file2']['lines'].append(line[n1:n1+n2])
    string_per_files['file3']['lines'].append(line[n1+n2:])

# write to file
for d in string_per_files.values():
    path, lines = d.values()
    with open(path, 'w') as fd:
        fd.write('\n'.join(lines))
```